# AKHQ ON AKS: Failed to read configuration file

Tags: docker, micronaut

When I try to deploy AKHQ on AKS I get the following error:

```
2022-01-27 14:07:06,353 ←[1;31mERROR←[0;39m ←[35mmain      ←[0;39m ←[36mi.m.runtime.Micronaut     ←[0;39m Error starting Micronaut server: Failed to read configuration file: /app/application.yml
```

The configuration file(`application.yml`) looks like this:

```
micronaut:
  security:
    enabled: false

akhq:
  server:
    access-log: # Access log configuration (optional)
      enabled: true # true by default
      name: org.akhq.log.access # Logger name
      format: "[Date: {}] [Duration: {} ms] [Url: {} {}] [Status: {}] [Ip: {}] [User: {}]" # Logger format

# list of kafka cluster available for akhq
  connections:
    kafka-cluster-ssl:
      properties:
        bootstrap.servers: "FQN-Address-01:9093,FQN-Address-02:9093,FQN-Address-03:909"
        security.protocol: SSL
        ssl.truststore.location: /app/truststore.jks
        ssl.truststore.password: truststor-pwd
        ssl.keystore.location: /app/keystore.jks
        ssl.keystore.password: keystore-pwd
        ssl.key.password: key-pwd
```

I passed also read permission to the file in Dockerfile but that didn't help.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM tchiotludo/akhq:0.20.0

# add ssl producer/consumer config and root ca file
ADD ./resources/ /app/

USER root
RUN chmod +r application.yml
RUN chmod +x gen-certs.sh
RUN ./gen-certs.sh
```

Comment: The problem isn't AKS. Run your container locally (`docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint=sh`) and exec into it to see if that `/app/application.yml` exists

Comment: Thank you. Iknow that is not about AKS. I assume that something is wrong with config. I can not run it locally. It should run on the dev env in AKS as Kafka and other stuff are running on it. I created a container already and exported their content and the config file app/application.yml and other stuff were there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an older version of AKHQ docker image and AKHQ is running now.